# Try to connect Android App running on Emulator to a Servlet running in localhost

Tags: java, android, servlets

I'm implementing an Android App which has to communicate with some java servlet to get data.
The connection between the app and the servlet is made by httpRequest.
The java servlet run on a Tomcat server which I've configured like that:[image]

The java servlet code run correctly, I tested it with the desktop version of the App.
The problem is when i try to connect the app to the servlet.
Here there's the code of the android activity that manage the connection to the servlet:

```
    private String user;
    String DEBUG_TAG = "debug";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        onStart();
    }

    public void log(View view) { //action performed when users click on login button

        EditText username= findViewById(R.id.username);
        EditText password= findViewById(R.id.password);
        String account_username=username.getText().toString();
        String account_password=password.getText().toString();

        String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/Ripetizioni/Login/?uname=" + account_username+ "&psw="+account_password;
        if(isOnLine()){
            new ExecuteLogin().execute(URL);
        }
        switch(user) {
            case "client":
                Intent i = new Intent(this, UserActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case "administrator":
                Intent ii = new Intent(this, AdminActivity.class);
                startActivity(ii);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private class ExecuteLogin extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                return getUser(params[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            setUser(s);
        }

    }

    public String getUser(String myurl) {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(myurl);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000); //milliseconds
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000); //milliseconds
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();
            int response = conn.getResponseCode();
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "The response is: " + response);
            return readIt(conn.getInputStream());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("async", ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }

    private String readIt(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(stream));
        String line;
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    public boolean isOnLine() {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
                getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            assert connMgr != null;
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            return (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());
        } else {
            assert connMgr != null;
            Network[] nets = connMgr.getAllNetworks();
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            for (Network net : nets) {
                NetworkInfo info = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(net);
                assert info != null;
                String tipo = info.getTypeName();
                boolean connessa = info.isConnected();
                if (connessa) {
                    String tip = "";
                    if (info.getType() == connMgr.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                        tip = "Mobile";
                    } else if (info.getType() == connMgr.TYPE_WIFI) {
                        tip = "WiFi";
                    }
                    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Mobile connected: " + tip);
                    String text = "internet connessa! " + tipo + " " + tip;
                    text += info.toString();
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "NO RETE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The code get some errors inside the "getUser" method and this is the console log:

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: it.repetition.test, PID: 10750
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.hashCode()' on a null object reference
        at it.repetition.test.LoginActivity.log(LoginActivity.java:73)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

If I debug the code, I get an exception in the "getUser" method like this:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://10.0.2.2:8080/Ripetizioni/Login/?uname=Mario&psw=012abc
```

Probably I did some configuration error or something like this, but I haven't a lot of practice with Android and I can't understand how to fix the bugs.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: `NullPointerException` Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.hashCode()' on a null object reference

Comment: I know that ther's a nullPointerException, ther's beacause the `getUser` method catch an exception and retrun null. The problem for me is beacause `getUser` find an exception.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to say. But from your log: `LoginActivity.java:73`  The code on line 73 causes the exception.